# как убрать отступ от шапки и тела

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div id="headerInner">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
        <ul class = "menu">
        <i class="fa fa-at" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>


        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-0">
                  <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Поле 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Поле 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Поле 3</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>

                <!-- поиск -->
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-wrapper" data-text=""> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Найти"></div> 
              </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </nav>

    <-- css файл -->

    * {
        line-height: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }



    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.5;
      color: #333;
      text-align: left;
      background-color: #3a4a54 !important;
    }

    ul {
      list-style:none;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration:none;
    }

    a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* -------------------------------
    Главные блоки
    ----------------------------------*/

    #wrapper {
            margin-top:40px;
            width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: auto  !important;
            }



    #headerInner {
            position:relative;
            border:0px solid #333;
            width:1200px;
            height:50px;
      margin:0 auto;
            margin-top:0px;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #669999; 
      }
    #navbarSupportedContent {
    padding: 0px;

    }

    .menu{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 100px;
    }

    i.fa.fa-at {
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    }

    i.fa.fa-bookmark {
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    }

    .input-wrapper {
      width: 500px;
      margin: 50px auto;
      position: relative;
    }
```

[image: как получилось]

Comment: у вас много где есть top и margin-top : обнуляйте до нужного результат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну вы же сами задали этот отступ для .input-wrapper {margin: 50px auto;}

Меняйте margin

```
.input-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
}
```